# WAS 8.5 com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.AdminException

Tags: java, eclipse, websphere

I am getting below error while start the WAS 8.5 server.

```
ADMU0116I: Tool information is being logged in file
           C:\Ibm_WAS8.5\profiles\June\logs\server1\startServer.log
ADMU0128I: Starting tool with the June profile
ADMU3100I: Reading configuration for server: server1
ADMU0111E: Program exiting with error:
           com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.AdminException
ADMU1211I: To obtain a full trace of the failure, use the -trace option.
ADMU0211I: Error details may be seen in the file:
           C:\Ibm_WAS8.5\profiles\June\logs\server1\startServer.log
```

Please refer the given below exception from startServer.log

```
[5/15/18 18:11:32:012 EDT] 00000001 AdminTool     A   ADMU0111E: Program exiting with error: com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.AdminException
    at com.ibm.ws.management.launcher.DefaultLaunchPlatformHelper.getDefaultBootclasspath(DefaultLaunchPlatformHelper.java:121)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.launcher.LaunchCommand.processBootstrapClasspathInfo(LaunchCommand.java:1689)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.launcher.LaunchCommand.setParamsFromJavaProcessDef(LaunchCommand.java:1227)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.launcher.LaunchCommand.setParamsFromProcessDef(LaunchCommand.java:632)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.launcher.LaunchCommand.init(LaunchCommand.java:376)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.launcher.LaunchCommand.<init>(LaunchCommand.java:270)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerLauncher.initializeRepositoryAndLauncher(WsServerLauncher.java:424)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerLauncher.runTool(WsServerLauncher.java:279)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.AdminTool.executeUtility(AdminTool.java:269)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerController.executeUtilityOnWindows(WsServerController.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerLauncher.main(WsServerLauncher.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:280)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got solution from the following links.
[listout-sdk](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/356264/why-does-the-managesdk-enableprofileall-command-fa/) and
[commands](https://studiofreya.com/2014/12/11/websphere-application-server-problems-when-changing-to-java7/)

```
cd /cydrive/c/IBM_8.5.5/WebSphere/AppServer/bin
./managesdk.bat -listAvailable
./managesdk.bat -enableProfileAll -sdkName 1.6_64
./managesdk.bat -setCommandDefault -sdkName 1.6_64
./managesdk.bat -setNewProfileDefault -sdkName 1.6_64
```

Restart the server.